# Kazam does not stop recording and open window to save video

Tags: desktop-recording, kazam

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I have had mixed results with kazam. Sometimes the recorder simply refuses to finish recording from the stop button and the main window never comes back up. I kill the app and lose the recording. Have others run into this issue? I see that Kazam does not have new releases after 2014 from here - https://launchpad.net/kazam. Is there a known fix for this issue? As an aside, any other suggested alternative tools?

Comment: Ya same issue. There is no fix yet

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. I switched to vokoscreen.

You can try other tools too in the below blog.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-record-screen-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux